# VSCode remote ssh -- how to automatically install extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

How do I install VSCode extensions in an SSH connection without doing it through the VSCode UI?  I have an environment that spins up a new VM for git branches, and it's really annoying to have to go manually install every extension for each new VM.

I've tried adding them to a devcontainer.json file, which is ignored (it only works on containers, not ssh, even in the newest release that's had some support for the file via ssh connections).

I could add a bunch of packages to vscode's settings, but I want to avoid that because what I install is different based on whether I'm looking at a rust service, node, etc and it's pretty pointless to install every conceivable package in every vm.

Comment: you can create an extension-pack extension, package this to a VSIX and use the command line of VSC to install this extension pack

Comment: any update on that one?

Answer (score 6):

#get extendsions ids

1. cmd:

   ```
   code --list-extensions
   //foo.bar
   //foo1.bar2
   ```
2. Visual Studio Code: Open settings file, add option:

   ```json
   "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": [
       "foo.bar",
    ]
   ```
3. ```
   ssh remote ssh rm ~/.vscode-server
   ```
4. vscode reconnect remote server

Comment: The source for this hack plus more info can be found on VSCode's website [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_always-installed-extensions).